# Are media queries with non media specifiers possible?

Tags: css

I swear I had this working, but it's not. Is such a thing possible?
I don't want to prefix the 100's of styles with `body:not(.phone)`

Thank you.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) and (body:not(.phone)) {

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NO. That's not how can do with @media queries. You must use like below:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {/*css rules not applicable before curly brace*/
   body:not(.phone){/*css rules must be within curly braces*/
      color: #f00;
   }
}
```

So, what you mean with @media queries is not possible.